# System.IO.FileNotFoundException - FFImageLoading: Setting Placeholder Failed

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, firebase, xamarin

Acabo de tomar un nuevo proyecto `Xamarin.Android` el cual me presenta un error que coincidió con un cambio de URL de lectura de las imágenes desde `Firebase Storage`, por lo que tampoco estoy seguro si el mensaje es debido al cambio en el link o no.

**El mensaje es el siguiente:**

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: https://PROYECTNAME.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/ICONS/SPLASH.jpg
  at FFImageLoading.DataResolvers.FileDataResolver.Resolve (System.String identifier, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00008] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Droid\DataResolvers\FileDataResolver.cs:15 
  at FFImageLoading.DataResolvers.WrappedDataResolver.Resolve (System.String identifier, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00020] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\DataResolvers\WrappedDataResolver.cs:21 
  at FFImageLoading.Work.ImageLoaderTask`3[TDecoderContainer,TImageContainer,TImageView].ShowPlaceholder (System.String path, System.String key, FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource source, System.Boolean isLoadingPlaceholder) [0x002b7] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Work\ImageLoaderTask.cs:544 
Setting placeholder failed
```

**Con 2 imagenes a veces si da el error, pero usualmente no; y con otras 2 imagenes casi siempre da el error. Entiendo que el error es básicamente porque no logra encontrar la imagen, pero lo raro es que:**

> 1. No sucede con todas las imagenes y todas estan en el mismo bucket y carpeta.
> 2. Las imagenes con las que da el error estan ahi. Si pego la URL en mi navegador las puedo visualizar sin problemas.

**El cambio de URL:**

El cambio de URL se debio a que ahora los iconos estan en un bucket publico para que la app no necesite pasar un Token para leer esos iconos que no continen ninguna fragilidad o vulnerabilidad estando publicos, también que acelera un poco el tiempo de carga de este modo. Y a como mencione anteriormente, solo sucede con algunas imagenes, hay aproximadamente 55 imagenes cargadas de la misma forma y sin problemas.

Las imagenes ahora se cargan asi:

```
https://NOMBREPROYECTO.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/Iconos/ICONO.png
```

Busque en la web pero los posts que encontré hacen referencia a `iOS` o a permisos habilitados de las imágenes (ya que las imágenes de los ejemplos de esos posts son imágenes locales).

¿Estoy pasando algo por alto?

**ACTUALIZACION:**

Ya se probo a darle un mayor tiempo de espera y un mayor numero de reintentos al ImageView trabajando con el `FFImageLoading` de esta forma y nada:

```
//Descargando imagen de "Cargando..."
                ImageView Icono = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.IconoPreloader);
                ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(uri)
                    .Retry(20, 500)
                    .Into(Icono);
```

Comment: Como las imágenes con las que falla, fallan a veces, ¿es posible que sea algo relacionado con el tamaño? Algún timeout porque son muy grandes?

Comment: Una recomendación muy buena y bastante instintiva considerando la poca info que puedo ofrecer al respecto. Sin embargo ya intente eso dándole un Retry(20, 500); y nada. Pero gracias @Alfabravo